# Use of Request and Response in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, http

What is the difference between "**Request**" and "**Response**" terminologies in ASP.net?
I am using ASP.net 3.5.

Suppose I have to make somebody understand about these terms. What should i say ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Request is what a web client sends to the web server. The Response is what the web server sends - well, in response. Both are defined in the HTTP specification. (How they are structured, what information and meta data they include, etc.)

ASP.Net encapsulates these concepts in respective classes to make them programmatically accessible.

### **Edit: Specific examples as requested in the comments:**

**Request.QueryString**

If you have a URL like the following:

`http://www.host.com/Page.aspx?name=Henry&lastName=Ford`

The part after the `?` is the *query string*. (`name=Henry&lastName=Ford <= The query string`)

This is one common way to pass arguments to the server as part of the *Request*. In your server code you can access these arguments by using `Request.QueryString`:

```
string name = Request.QueryString["name"];
string lastName = Request.QueryString["lastName"];
```

**Response.Redirect**

Your server received a *Request* for a page and you want to *redirect* to another location. With the `Response.Redirect()` method, you add a specific piece of information to the *Response* that causes the browser to immediately go to this other page.

```
// This tells the browser to load google
Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: so how to understand the Request.Querystring and Response.Redirect in context of above definition. Can you send the Edit in your answer ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=VS.90%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirect%28v=VS.90%29.aspx. Start reading. At some point you have to take responsibility for your own learning.

Comment: Can you explain more in details about Request for Request.QueryString ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a IIS (Internet Information Services) Server.. In ASP.Net, you can **Request** for data from the server, and what the server sends you is a **Response**