# getting incoming http request in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

I have an external application (written from a different company) which fires some requests to my asp.net web application when hitting a button. My application is running on https://localhost:59917/Main.aspx. If I hit the request button in the external program it says the following:

```
08:53:25 Requesting web page : https://localhost:59917/Main.aspx?token=mcQYVqoe7LxmBx7jgHBq6FtXXp4uPCzX0FDZStiZDFMDd4l6oB3x5CgysXJKgy2y
```

So this app is now requesting my web application. I now have to get the given arguments of this request (in this example I need to read the argument `token`). I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753922/use-of-request-and-response-in-asp-net) and tried the following in my code behind (Main.aspx.cs):

```
protected void btnListener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string token = Request.QueryString["token"];
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertToken", "alert('" + token + "');", true);
}
```

But this returns an empty string. Since I'm new to asp.net and web development I'm not sure if I understand the `HttpRequest` class correctly. Is this even the right way to get the arguments I need?

Comment: The code above should be moved presumably in the main.aspx.cs file under the Page_Load method when IsPostBack == false.

Comment: Why in `Page_Load()` method? This method is only fired on startup, right? But the request could be fired anytime.

Comment: Page_Load is fired everytime a request arrives to the page. So, if the external application makes a request to main.aspx passing the mentioned querystring you should receive a Page_Load event in your main.aspx.cs

Comment: Oh, okay. I tried it and it works, I now have the requested token. I'll keep this in reminder. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the external application makes a request to the main.aspx page then a *Page_Load* events occurs in the [Page Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Thus you can simply move your code in the *Page_Load* event handler already written for you by the designer

```
protected void main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string token = Request.QueryString["token"];
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertToken", "alert('" + token + "');", true);
}
```

Actually *Page_Load* events are called everytime a request for the page comes trough the ASP.NET engine also when you click a button on the same page.

Before the call to the event handler for the button clicked you receive a call to the Page_Load event handler. You can discover if this is the first time that your page loads looking at the *IsPostBack* property (true when the load is the result of an action performed on the same page, false when the page is loaded to present its interface to the end-user)